# Frontend developer screening - abstract coding

Tags: abstraction

I received some kind of theoretical assessment after applying for a Junior HTML/CSS developer offer.

I totally have no idea what the abstract programing language is. Is anyone able to solve this task?

Below you can find block of abstract coding. What should be instead of suspension points **"..."**?

`$ul .= wrap(wrap($name, wrap($url, '<a href="|">') . '|</a>'), '<li>...');`

What is this function for and how it actually works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace the `...` by `|</li>`.

It seems that the `wrap()` function takes the first parameter and puts it instead of the `|` char of the second parameter.

If `$url` contains `https://www.google.com` and `$name` contains `Google` then the result stored in the `$ul` variable will be `<li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>`.

Comment: Ok, so it means my answer was good. I took similar way of thinking during this assessment. Thanks for your time and help ;)

Answer (score 1):

The point of it being abstract is that it's not a specific language, it's trying to test your logical thinking skills.
That being said, it looks like the wrap function accepts two strings, the second should contain a | character which will be replaced with the first argument.

The answer should be `|</li>`.

Comment: Ok, my final answer during this assessment was the same. Thanks for your time and help.